# Need help traversing JSON object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, wcf, json

I have code that calls a WCF service and returns a JSON string to the client. Below is the javascript function I am trying to use to parse the JSON but can not figure out how to traverse it.

Here is the function

```
loadDropDown: function(result, ddl, defaultItem) {
    var _data = result.get_object();
    //Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(result, true);

    this.clearDropDown(ddl);
    this.createOption(ddl, defaultItem, '');
    for (var i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
        var _item = _data[i];
        var _option = this.createOption(ddl, _item.Text, _item.Value);
    }
    ddl.disabled = false;
}
```

Here is the JSON

```
{
     "d": "[{\"Attributes\":{\"Keys\":[],\"Count\":0,\"CssStyle\":{\"Keys\":[],\"Count\":0,\"Value\":null}},\"Enabled\":true,\"Selected\":false,\"Text\":\"Lexus\",\"Value\":\"Lexus\"},{\"Attributes\":{\"Keys\":[],\"Count\":0,\"CssStyle\":{\"Keys\":[],\"Count\":0,\"Value\":null}},\"Enabled\":true,\"Selected\":false,\"Text\":\"Acura\",\"Value\":\"Acura\"}]"
}
```

any suggestions on why this is not working? Note: I am not using jquery in the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be generating that json. Instead, you should be outputting

```
{
     "d": [{"Attributes":{"Keys":[],"Count":0,"CssStyle":{"Keys":[],"Count":0,"Value":null}},"Enabled":true,"Selected":false,"Text":"Lexus","Value":"Lexus"},{"Attributes":{"Keys":[],"Count":0,"CssStyle":{"Keys":[],"Count":0,"Value":null}},"Enabled":true,"Selected":false,"Text":"Acura","Value":"Acura"}]
}
```

(quotes removed from `"d"` value)

There's no reason to convert json to a string before putting it in a json object! Just put the json straight in.

Comment: How would I get to the Text and Value properties?

Comment: @TampaRich: This all seems to come down to how WCF works. You should add that as a tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do eval(_data) before you use it as a javascript array.

for ex:

```
var _rawdata = result.get_object();
var _data = eval(_rawdata);
//Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(result, true);

this.clearDropDown(ddl);
this.createOption(ddl, defaultItem, '');
for (var i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
    var _item = _data[i];
    var _option = this.createOption(ddl, _item.Text, _item.Value);
}
ddl.disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just [eval()](http://www.json.org/js.html) the object (or use [JSON parsing from Crockford](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)) and access your properties in regular object notation. You may need to unescape your identifiers first, though.